# Problema al utilizar Ajax para usar Api de Google Maps

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

Quiero usar ajax para utilizar una api de Google Maps, pero no se en este caso como sería.

Este es un ejemplo de la documentación de Google Maps de como debe ser la ruta.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA&waypoints=optimize:true|Barossa+Valley,SA|Clare,SA|Connawarra,SA|McLaren+Vale,SA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

En el javascript tengo lo siguiente:

```
var waypoint = [];

function ordenLista(){

    $.ajax({
        url:"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json",
        dataType:"json",
        data:{origin:{lat:posActualLat, lng:posActualLng},
              destination:{lat:-34.911946, lng:-56.160502},
              waypoints: (aca no se como poner) },

    });

}
```

La variable waypoint la cargo con varias direcciones. Ej:

waypoint = ["direccion1","direccion2","direcion3","direcion4"]; estas son las direcciones por las que va a marcar la ruta.

No se como llenar el campo `waypoints:` porque iría mi array `waypoint` y `optimize=true` para que me de la mejor ruta.

Si saben como puedo hacerlo o tienen alguna otra forma de hacer lo mismo se los agradezco.

Comment: Para poder crear un código de como podrías iterar tu arreglo de `waypoint` es necesario que pongas un ejemplo de que contiene el mismo.

Comment: Es un array de string, contiene las direcciones por las cuales quiero que marque la ruta.

Comment: waypoint = ["direccion1", "direccion2", "direccion3", "direccion4"]; algo asi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de convertir tu arreglo de `waypoints`, podrías ser esta:

```
// Datos a modo de ejemplo
var waypoints = [
    {id: '1', dir: 'Teresa Cabana de Moreno, Canelones, Departamento de Canelones, Uruguay', desc: 'Piso 1 - Dpto 2'},
    {id: '2', dir: 'Ansina, Sauce, Departamento de Canelones, Uruguay', desc: 'Casa azul'}
  ],
  posActualLat = -34.451757,
  posActualLng = -56.3960837;

// Funcion transformadora
function translateWaypoints(waypoints, optimizar) {
  var params = [];
  if (optimizar === true) {
    params.push('optimize:true');
  }
  $.each(waypoints, function(idx, waypoint) {
    params.push(waypoint.dir);
  });
  return params.join('|');
}

function ordenLista() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        key: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
        origin: posActualLat + ',' + posActualLng,
        destination: '-34.911946,-56.160502',
        waypoints: translateWaypoints(waypoints, true)
      }
    })
    .done(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
}

ordenLista();
```

Comment: Hola, tuve que hacer un cambio en el array waypoints, lo cargo de esta forma:  waypoints.push({
                        id:${reparto.pedido.id},
                        dir:'${reparto.pedido.direccion}',
                        desc:'${reparto.pedido.descripcion}'});                                                pero me da error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined(…)) al hacer esto: cadena += waypoints.dir.join('|'); hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo? Disculpa y gracias!

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Tal como se hace en los ejemplos de la misma api `waypoint` es un arreglo de direcciones.  [Ejemplo Google Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints?hl=es-419) aqui en este ejemplo, tienes un selector multiple con varias posibilidades para seleccionar recorrer :

```
<select multiple="" id="waypoints">
    <option value="montreal, quebec">Montreal, QBC</option>
    <option value="toronto, ont">Toronto, ONT</option>
    <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
    <option value="winnipeg, mb">Winnipeg</option>
    <option value="fargo, nd">Fargo</option>
    <option value="calgary, ab">Calgary</option>
    <option value="spokane, wa">Spokane</option>
</select>
```

En donde se recorren las opciones seleccionadas y se cargan en un arreglo.

El arreglo `waypts` se declara vacio, se obtiene el elemento html con id `waypoints` y se guarda en la variable `checkboxArray`. Luego esta variable se recorrer y se van agregando item por item al arreglo `waypoints` donde `checkboxArray[i].value` es el `value` del selector : `<option value="toronto, ont">Toronto, ONT</option>`

```
var waypts = [];
var checkboxArray = document.getElementById('waypoints');
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
   if (checkboxArray.options[i].selected) {
      waypts.push({
          location: checkboxArray[i].value,
          stopover: true
      });
   }
}
```